# The Function That Adds Twice Records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When i run this function:

```
function yemek_onay ($id, $session) {
global $db;
global $suAnSaat;
$hasta = $db->query("SELECT * FROM hastalar WHERE id = '{$id}'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$kullanici = sess_info($session);
$ogun = ogun($suAnSaat);
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO yemek_log SET hasta_id = '{$id}', ogun = '{$ogun}', kullanici_id = '{$kullanici["id"]}'")->execute();
return $result;}
```

It adds twice record to table. I dont have any idea why it do this.

Table view:
[image]

Comment: check this `hasta_id = '{$id}'`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: Maybe you are calling `yemek_onay()` twice???

Comment: Why do you do the first `SELECT` query? You never use `$hasta` for anything.

Comment: You're right. Its my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are running the command twice with a `->query` and an `->execute`. Each of them will perform the statement once, as you have BOTH it'll run twice. Get rid of either of one of them and it'll work. I'd suggest using a prepared statement, dropping the `query` and replacing it with the `execute` version as it'll make it more secure.